# How to install gems over ruby 2?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation

I just installed ruby 2 on MacMountainLion, how to install gems? Actually I have both installed but there is something wrong. Maybe a fresh installation would solve.

```
macbook:~m$ gem install rails
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
macbook:~ m$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
macbook:~ m$ gem -v
2.0.3
macbook:~ m$
```

Comment: It looks like you need to install openssl development libraries as it was extensions build that failed.

Answer (score 0):

Installing gem like rails needs lot of dependent libraries which you have to download and install it manually

Alternatively you can try using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) to install all the dependent libraries. If you are new to ROR development I strongly recommend you to use [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) to manage different versions of ruby

Once you have installed all the necessary dependent libraries using Homebrew then Its fairly straight forward to install a gem, execute the following after replacing "gemname" with the gem you are interested in

```
gem install <<gemname>>
```

Comment: @tatojo I'm not able to see your output, check your comment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but fixed it as follows:

Apparently OS X Mountain Lion has an older version of OpenSSL than Ruby 2 will tolerate.  Download and install the latest OpenSSL using `./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl; make; sudo make install`. Then build Ruby using `./configure --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/openssl; make; sudo make install`.  Ruby's configure complains that `--with-openssl-dir` is an unknown option, but the build apparently uses it anyway because anything that depends on SSL, including gem installs, now works.